# Bash to python scripting

Tags: python, bash

i want to create a script in python, but having this error. 
Can please anyone help me.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./python_test.py", line 7, in <module>
    if i in range(1, 254):
NameError: name 'i' is not defined
```

==================================

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
if i in range(1, 254):
   all=os.system("echo 10.11.1.i")
   print(all)
```

======================================

```
for ip in $(seq 1 254);do echo 10.11.1.$ip;done
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To loop through all the numbers in the range you use `for`, not `if`. Also, `range()` doesn't include the ending value, so if you want to go up to `254`, you have to use `range(1, 255)`.

```
for i in range(1, 255):
```

Variables aren't expanded inside strings. Use string formatting.

```
allresults=os.system("echo 10.11.1.%d" % i)
print(allresults)
```

You also shouldn't use `all` as a variable name, it's the name of a built-in Python function.

Comment: Also, “all” is a builtin, so you shouldn’t override it.

Comment: Just the last thing. why i'm getting this 10.11.1.250
<built-in function all>
10.11.1.251
<built-in function all> i want to remove built-in function.. And can you please tell me why we use %d????

Comment: You're getting that because `all` is the name of a built-in function. Use `print(allresults)`

Comment: and can you please tell me if i have couple of ips in txt file how can i add open file in my program?? to read and do the same echo process?

Comment: You need to learn the language, this isn't a Python school. There are tutorials on reading from files.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code, you need to **change the if statement to for**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
for i in range(1, 255):
   all_=os.system("echo 10.11.1."+str(i))
   print(all_)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this, the new f-string (over python 3.6.0):

```
import os
for i in range(1, 255):
   all_=os.system(f"echo 10.11.1.{i}")
   print(all_)
```

Or str.format:

```
import os
for i in range(1, 255):
   all_=os.system("echo 10.11.1.{}".format(i))
   print(all_)
```

*Note: renamed to `all_` because `all` is a builtin keyword and you son't want to overwrite it*